# Get pointer to registered field in the wizard

Tags: qt

Can I get access to the widget of registred field in the QWizardPage?

```
QLineEdit* fld = new QLineEdit;

// register
registerField( "test", fld );
....
// Somewhere in wizard
QLineEdit* field = ?
```

Comment: So you want access to the widget itself, not just its value?

Comment: Yes, to the widget, to have ability to change its property, for example to disable or enable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `QWizardPage` isn't really designed to do this — which is why the `field` function just returns the widget's contents, not a pointer to it.

Looking at [the source code for `QWizardPage::registerField`](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/57756e72adf2081137b97f0e689dd16c770d10b1%3asrc/gui/dialogs/qwizard.cpp#L3900), getting to the fields is going to be nasty: they're stored in the `QWizardPrivate` class, which is used to isolate the private implementation of the QWizard class from its public interface (see [Qt's D-Pointer write-up](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Dpointer) for more information about this approach).

I don't recommend trying to figure out how to actually expose the internals of `QWizardPrivate` to your own code. That's because the whole reason `QWizardPrivate` exists is to allow Qt to completely change the private data and implementation in a minor release, without affecting compiled code — it's a moving target.

The simplest solution is to store your own pointer to the QLineEdit externally, if at all possible. For example, if you're subclassing QWizardPage, try creating a "shadow" field map of your own.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a unique name to the widget, then find it in the wizard's children. Recall that widgets are QObjects. This technique applies to all QObjects and is not specific to the wizard, or even to widgets.

```
char const fieldName[] = "MyCoolField";

fld->setObjectName(fieldName);
...
QLineEdit * field = wizardPage->findChild<QLineEdit*>(fieldName);
if (field) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Does it get added to the QWizardPage's children? I couldn't find the code that does that in qwizard.cpp.

Comment: @AlexP Well, it needs to be a child of some widget. If looking at page's children won't find it, then looking at the wizard's children will. That's the beauty of the widgets: if it's within some top-level widget, then all you need is to start at the top level widget and you will find it there. You don't even need to know what widget to look at: just check all the widgets available from `qApp->topLevelWidgets()`.